# How to merge multiple exr into a single multilayer exr?

Tags: image-processing, image

Are there some tools or softwares to merge multiple exr into a single multilayer exr?

I only find a tool to split a multilayer exr into multiple exr.

And it seems that Blender, Mitsuba, Darktable all can't do this.

Should I write a tool myself using OpenEXR?

Comment: I haven't looked at it in years, but it might be worth looking through [ILM's source for OpenEXR](http://openexr.org/).